# How to show json data in Listview with Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, json, listview, retrofit2

I'm a newbie about Android programming :(

I have no idea to set Listview for show data
How to Show data in Listview.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


  private static final String TAG = "fong";
  ListView listView;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
              .baseUrl(UdacityService.BASE_URL)
              .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
              .build();

    UdacityService service = retrofit.create(UdacityService.class);
    Call<UdacityCatalog> requestCatalog = service.listCatalog();

    requestCatalog.enqueue(new Callback<UdacityCatalog>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<UdacityCatalog> call, Response<UdacityCatalog> response) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {

          Log.i(TAG,"Errorr: " +response.code());
        }else{
          UdacityCatalog catalog =response.body();


          for (Course c : catalog.courses){
            Log.i(TAG,c.title);

            Log.i(TAG,"--------------");

          }
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<UdacityCatalog> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Errorr: " + t.getMessage());
      }
    });

  }
}
```

I want  to show data `c.title` in ListView

`Log.i(TAG,c.title)` show

```
I/fong: Richard Kalehoff

I/fong: Firebase Analytics: iOS

I/fong: Firebase Analytics: Android
```

Thanks for yor help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It`s easy, First you have to add a ListView component in your Layout:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And then, find it in your JAVA code and put it in a instance variable:

```
ListView listview;

    //in your onCreate() after setContentView():
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

You have to create a list with all your titles:

```
List<String> courses = new ArrayList<>();
  for (Course c : catalog.courses){
          courses.add(c.title);
          }
```

Now, you have to create a SimpleAdapter and pass your data to it:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.r.layout.simple_list_item_1, courses);
```

And finally, add your adapter in your `ListView`:

```
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: thanks for your help! But I get error in line `this.courses.add(c.title);` `courses` is cannot resolve symbol 'courses'

Comment: you have to declare the ListView variable in your Activity, you can change the name of it.

Comment: try to remove the "this"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142628/discussion-between-arr-s-and-luiz-fernando-salvaterra).

Comment: @ARR.s I change my answer, take a look

Answer (score 0):

Take a list of Course

```
List<Course> courseList = catalog.courses;
```

then make a custom list Adapter and from this list get the title and show it in textView of the list

```
textView.setText(courseList.get(position).title);
```